# Can I denote the language of each page of my website so that Google won't show contents of a foreign to a user?

Tags: html, search, localization, seo, multilingual

I have a website that contains both Chinese and English contents (and they are different, NOT translations of each others). When some English users search the name of my site on Google, some Chinese contents also appear on the search result. Can I avoid this? Is there any HTML markup I can use to indicate the content language of each page? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Google's answer to this question is found on [Webmaster Tools here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192#1).

Comment: Asking how to denote the language of your documents is on-topic, but asking how/if Google Search handles this is off-topic. If you are interested in the first part, you could [edit] your question accordingly; if you are interested in the second part, you might want to ask it on [webmasters.se] and close this question here.

Answer (score 2):

Google ignores HTML code when determining language (such as `LANG` attributes). Instead it determines the page's language from the content.
They suggest having different subdomains or URL indicators for differing content (e.g. en.mypage.com and cn.mypage.com - or mypage.com/cn/content) and making sure boilerplate code is different (your site headers, navigation, etc should be localized, not just the content body).

More information is available on [Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192#1)